# Can not convert long to long in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, long-integer

During the implementing of a Java project, I encountered a weird error. When I try to cast long value to long I get the error - *"Can not convert Long to long"*. The code fragments are given below.

```
ObjectsIterator it = castFromBoth.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    long peopleOid = (long)it.next();            
    g.getAttribute(peopleOid, peopleNameType, value);          
    System.out.println("Hello " + value.getString());
}
```

Comment: Did you perhaps create your own `Long` class? Anyway I can't reproduce this error. Could you create and post short code example which will let us actually reproduce your problem?

Comment: Also can you tell us which version of Java you are using?

Comment: I changed it.next() to it.next().longValue() and it is OK now

Comment: Is it possible that you are using Java 1.4 or even older version of Java? If yes then in age of Java 8  you should mention such important detail.

Comment: No I am using version 1.8

Comment: What is the return type of `next()` method? Is it declared to return `Object` or `Long`?

Comment: it is Object - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/apirefs.1112/e17493/oracle/jdevimpl/audit/util/ObjectsIterator.html

Comment: Then how can you invoke `longValue()` method from `Object` reference?

Comment: yes, it is weird but it worked like that :)

Comment: It is more then weird, it is close to impossible. It looks like you are not telling us something about your code/project which kind of makes it useless for other readers with same problem. Could you update your question with more details which would allow us to reproduce this error?

Comment: In Eclipse it shows that `longValue()` return type is Long but in documentation (which I commented) was published that return type is `Object`. So, code is here - http://pastebin.com/NR21WSYp.

Comment: It seems that previously you gave us wrong documentation since it looks like `ObjectsIterator` comes from `com.sparsity.sparksee.gdb`. In that case its [`next()` method](http://sparsity-technologies.com/downloads/javadoc-java/html/com/sparsity/sparksee/gdb/ObjectsIterator.html#next()) really returns `Long` type which explains why you are able to use `longValue()`. But it is still strange why you ware not able to use it this way `long peopleOid = (long)it.next();` or even `long peopleOid = it.next();`. [Auto|Un]boxing should handle this for you automatically without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
long peopleOid = it.next().longValue()
```

([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#longValue())).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Long peopleOid = it.next(); //it.next() return a long wrapped in a Long Object
```

You end up with a Long object but with autoboxing you may use it like the primitive long with no problems.

Comment: Autoboxing/unboxing should add `Long` cast automatically `long peopleOid = (long)new Object();` compiles fine.

Comment: @Pshemo Yeah, the cast is unnecessary, i'm removing it. Tell me if you think it's better this way for comprehension.

Comment: @Pshemo just read your edit, maybe in his case the issue is with which version of java he is using, if i recall correctly the automatic cast of Long is post Java 5

Comment: Yes, lack of boxing/unboxing which was added in Java 5 may be related to this problem. Will have to wait for OP response to my comment.

Comment: I changed it.next() to it.next().longValue() and it is OK now.